# Drag and drop with RXjs

Tags: drag-and-drop, rxjs

I'm struggling with a drag and drop behavior with RXJS. I would like to start drag an element after 250ms mouse down for not hijack click events on that element.

So far the start drag works but stop drag never get called. Anyone know why?

```
let button = document.querySelector('.button');

let mouseDownStream = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(button, 'mousedown');
let mouseUpStream = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(button, 'mouseup');

let dragStream = mouseDownStream
  .flatMap((event) => {
    return Rx.Observable
      .return(event)
      .delay(250)
      .takeUntil(mouseUpStream)
  });

let dropStream = mouseUpStream
  .flatMap((event) => {
    return Rx.Observable
      .return(event)
      .skipUntil(dragStream)
  });

dragStream.subscribe(event => console.log('start drag'));
dropStream.subscribe(event => console.log('stop drag'));
```

[JSBin](https://jsbin.com/zefajevuki/edit?js,console,output)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've updated your code-sample to make it run, what I did:

- exchanged the `flatMap`s with `switchMap`s (`switchMap` is an alias for `flatMapLatest`) this will ensure that it only takes the latest events and in case a new event is emitted, it will cancel any old subevent => in this case `flatMap` might work okay, but it is safer to use `switchMap`, also a rule of thumb: when in doubt: use `switchMap`
- `dropStream` is based on/initiated by `dragStream` now
- removed the `skipUntil`, which was a racing-condition issue because it would have first triggered after the next dragStream-emission after some mouseUp (which would require traveling back in time)
- exchanged the mouseUp-target from `button` to `document` (more a convenience-thing, and not really essential for the while thing to work)

```js
let button = document.querySelector('.button');

let mouseDownStream = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(button, 'mousedown');
let mouseUpStream = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document, 'mouseup');

let dragStream = mouseDownStream
  .switchMap((event) => {
    return Rx.Observable
      .return(event)
      .delay(250)
      .takeUntil(mouseUpStream)
  });

let dropStream = dragStream
  .switchMap(() => mouseUpStream.take(1))

dragStream.subscribe(event => console.log('start drag'));
dropStream.subscribe(event => console.log('stop drag'));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/4.1.0/rx.all.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<button class="button">Button</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It still doesn't work as expected. It's working the first time you drag and drop. After that, when clicking the button the stop drag gets logged every time

Comment: True, I missed that - but that was a really obvious fix by adding a `.take(1)` - anyone could have seen that ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Universal drag event with TypeScript and newer rxjs

```
export const DragEvent = (selector:string):Observable<boolean> => {

  //element where the drag event should be recorded (make sure element is in the dom)
  const elem = document.querySelector(selector);

  // touch events to handle mobile devices
  const touchStart$ = fromEvent<TouchEvent>(elem, 'touchstart');

  const touchEnd$ = fromEvent<TouchEvent>(elem, 'touchend');

  const touchMove$ = fromEvent<TouchEvent>(elem, 'touchmove');

  // mouse events for desktop users
  const mouseDown$ = fromEvent<MouseEvent>(elem, 'mousedown');

  const mouseUp$ = fromEvent<MouseEvent>(elem, 'mouseup');

  const mouseMove$ = fromEvent<MouseEvent>(elem, 'mousemove');

  //Mouse drag event
  const mouseDragging$ = mouseMove$.pipe(
    skipUntil(mouseDown$),
    takeUntil(mouseUp$)
  );

  // 
  const mapToBoolean = (bool) => map(() => bool);

  //universal drag event will emit true on drag (desktop/mobile) optional:add touchStart$ to the merge.
  const move$ = merge(mouseDragging$, touchMove$).pipe(mapToBoolean(true);

  //universal end of drag event will emit false on drag end (desktop/mobile)
  const end$ = merge(mouseUp$, touchEnd$).pipe(mapToBoolean(false);

  //merged to return true or false depending on user dragg
  return merge(move$, end$).pipe(distinctUntilChanged());

}
```